# Running TYPO3 in Docker via wget ''

Tags: php, docker, typo3, docker-compose

I'm running few Docker Containers view at the Code below. I would like to integrate the TYPO3 via w get but get an ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build: ADD failed: stat /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder400003814/|: no such file or directory how can i solve it? and move the necessary folders into my www/ path thanks :)

`docker-compose up -d`

```html
`docker-compose.yml`

    version: '2'
        services:
        version: '2'
services:
  #######################################
  # PHP application Docker container
  #######################################
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    links:
      - mysql
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
#######################################
# MySQL server
#######################################
  mysql:
    build:
      context: docker/mysql/
      dockerfile: MySQL-5.7.Dockerfile
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - etc/environment.yml
    networks:
    - php-network
#######################################
# PHP MY ADMIN
#######################################
  myphpadmin:
    build:
      context: docker/myphpadmin
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    links:
    - mysql
    ports:
    - 8080:80
    environment:
    - PMA_HOST=mysql
    - VIRTUAL_PORT=80
    networks:
    - php-network

networks:
    php-network:
      driver: bridge
```

```html
`Dockerfile` for PHP & APACHE


    FROM webdevops/php-apache-dev:ubuntu-16.04

    ENV PROVISION_CONTEXT "development"

    # Configure volume/workdir
    WORKDIR /app/

Typo3 `Dockerfile`

FROM ubuntu:latest

ENV TYPO3_VERSION 7.6.16

# Install apache, PHP, and supplimentary programs. openssh-server, curl, and lynx-cur are for debugging the container.
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install \
    apache2 php7.0 php7.0-mysql libapache2-mod-php7.0 curl lynx-cur php7.0-curl php7.0-gd php-imagick php7.0-soap php7.0-xml php7.0-zip

# Enable apache mods.
    RUN a2enmod php7.0
    RUN a2enmod rewrite

# Update the PHP.ini file, enable <? ?> tags and quieten logging.
    RUN sed -i "s/short_open_tag = Off/short_open_tag = On/" /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
    RUN sed -i "s/error_reporting = .*$/error_reporting = E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE/" /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini

ADD https://get.typo3.org/7.6 | tar -xzf - && \
RUN cd /var/www/html && \
    ln -s typo3_src-* typo3_src && \
    ln -s typo3_src/index.php && \
    ln -s typo3_src/typo3 && \
    ln -s typo3_src/_.htaccess .htaccess && \
    mkdir typo3temp && \
    mkdir typo3conf && \
    mkdir fileadmin && \
    mkdir uploads && \
    touch FIRST_INSTALL && \
    chown -R www-data. .

# Manually set up the apache environment variables
    ENV APACHE_RUN_USER www-data
    ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP www-data
    ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/log/apache2
    ENV APACHE_LOCK_DIR /var/lock/apache2
    ENV APACHE_PID_FILE /var/run/apache2.pid

    # Expose apache.
    EXPOSE 80

# Copy this repo into place.
    ADD www /var/www/site

# Update the default apache site with the config we created.
    ADD etc/apache-config.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

# By default start up apache in the foreground, override with /bin/bash for interative.
    CMD /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND
```

Comment: If you are as sloppy in your code as in your writing of English, it's no wonder you have problems getting things to run. [so] tries to be a quality Q&A site, so please pay somewhat more attention to punctuation, spelling, and formatting of your future posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is however not really TYPO3 related.
I would suggest that you take a look at https://github.com/webdevops/TYPO3-docker-boilerplate which is well tested and just works out of the box.

Comment: yeah i already know this solution but its not the point i would like to setup my own env to underst.and how does it work to be more familiar with docker and typo3 configuration. So do u have any suggestions how i can get typo3 in it? :)